# tumblr json meta with php

Tags: php, json, tumblr

I am using the Tumblr api v2 with php, it's work but this code :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Authenticate via OAuth
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client(
  'my',
  'key',
  'is',
  'good'
);
// Make the request
$post=$client->getUserInfo();
echo(json_encode($post));
?>
```

would be like this (https://api.tumblr.com/console)

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": { ... }
}
```

and I've got the response part only with no meta :

```
{"user":{"name":"my name","likes":0,… }}
```

How can I get the meta ? I try $post->meta and $client->meta but this is stupid tests…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is lines 383 and 421 of `Client.php`

```
private function getRequest($path, $options, $addApiKey)
{
    $response = $this->makeRequest('GET', $path, $options, $addApiKey);

    return $this->parseResponse($response);
}
```

AND

```
private function parseResponse($response)
{
    $response->json = json_decode($response->body);
    if ($response->status < 400) {
        return $response->json->response;
    } else {
        throw new RequestException($response);
    }
}
```

Every call you make gets parsed before you get it.  You will only get the response, never the meta unless there is an error, in which case you will get an exception.

So, read the code before saying "this is stupid".

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/blob/master/lib/Tumblr/API/Client.php#L421) line you shouldn't worry about metadata. The php client takes care of any response code >400 and throws a [Tumblr\API\RequestException](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/blob/master/lib/Tumblr/API/RequestException.php). So what you really wanna do is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
try {
  // Authenticate via OAuth
  $client = new Tumblr\API\Client(
    'my',
    'key',
    'is',
    'good'
  );
  $post=$client->getUserInfo();
  echo(json_encode($post));
} catch(Tumblr\API\RequestException $e) {
  //handle na exception here
}
?>
```